# Putting router names in traceroute hops?

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, internal-dns, networking

We have a number of sites that are interconnected via VPN tunnels. When troubleshooting issues I regularly find myself running traceroute to see the path the workstation takes to access a remote device within our WAN.

If I run a traceroute on a sites public IP address the router name shows up, this is because I requested our service provider configured an rDNS record for each of our sites public IPs.

However, when I traceroute an internal IP such as `192.168.5.100`, I only get the IP's of the routers - not the names. Our main site has a DNS server running on our Domain Controller. I've added a PTR record for each of the subnets and now when running a traceroute from the main site to a remote branch the router names show up.

How can I make the router names show up when running a traceroute from remote branch to main site? Would all of the remote branches need to have the main site's DNS server as their primary IP and a public DNS server (Google, for example) as a backup?

The remote branches don't all require active directory integration so they aren't all using the main sites DNS server. I am concerned about what would happen if the VPN tunnel drops and whether that would render the remote branches unable to access the internet due to DNS availability.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The client on which you run traceroute needs to be able to do the reverse lookup.
So yes, you need to configure to use a DNS server on those clients which actually can resolve these IPs.

Configuring a potentially unstable primary DNS server is a bad idea.
If your primary DNS server is down, you usually have the problem that the clients run into a long timeout until they try the backup DNS server.
This more or less makes your internet access unusable.

The preferred solution would be to have dedicated branch DNS server, which acts as a slave for the primary DNS server.